# What does "such as" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

The sentence that I'm talking about is

> I need a bag **such as** a doctor carries.

Answer (score 1):

It means, I need a bag "similiar to one" a doctor carries.   It could be rephrased as , "I need a doctor's bag."  The first sentence could be used if you just need a bag - similar to - a doctors bag...perhaps with similar size/professional look...Whereas the second, "I need a doctor's bag." implies you are a doctor and need a bag for a doctor.

Answer (score -1):

The following sentence is incorrect:

> I need a bag such as a doctor carries.

Correct alternatives include:

> I need a bag such as **the one** a doctor carries.
>
> ---
>
> I need a bag such as **the ones doctors carry**.
>
> ---
>
> I need a bag **like the one a** doctor carries.
>
> ---
>
> I need a bag **similar to those used by** doctors.
>
> ---
>
> I need a bag **of the same kind as those used by** doctors.
>
> ---
>
> I need a bag **of the same kind as a bag** a doctor carries.
>
> ---
>
> I need a bag **of the same kind as the bags** doctors carry.
>
> ---
>
> I need a bag **of the same kind as those which** doctors carry.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the original sentence. Where do you think the problem with it lies?

Comment: The original sentence is **not** incorrect.